# More than one? What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

At first there may be more than one,
Next your view will get things done.
Next, half a banana will help us out,
Then used in a question, but do not pout.
The beginning of the finale is the key,
To help you see what I might be.
Know people use me for different things.
I might make it difficult to sing.
So carefully analyze, reason, finalize,
What I might be, then eat some pies.

Comment: This riddle is brilliant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> SCARF.

*At first there may be more than one,*

> The letter **S** is used for pluralising (as in the OP's previous riddle).

*Next your view will get things done.*

> A view is what you see, and "see" sounds like **C**.

*Next, half a banana will help us out,*

> Half the letters in the word "banana" are **A**'s.

*Then used in a question, but do not pout.*

> Questions such as "are you here?" contains the word "are", which sounds like **R**.

*The beginning of the finale is the key,*

> The first letter of the word "finale" is **F**.

Putting together everything we've got so far gives the word I mentioned at the start.

*To help you see what I might be.

 Know people use me for different things.*

> Scarves can be used for warmth or as fashion accessories.

*I might make it difficult to sing.*

> If you're wearing a scarf, it's hard to sing through it.

*So carefully analyze, reason, finalize,*

> This is an acrostic: "**S**o **c**arefully **a**nalyze, **r**eason, **f**inalize".

*What I might be, then eat some pies.*

> I'm not sure what pies have to do with it! A red herring?

Comment: Because pies are awesome at all times :). Great job. Some extra thoughts: "are" is often used in a question, but "r" is not found in pout. Also, Scarves are now a fashion accessory for women even in the summer (at least for my wife) but others use for warmth.

Comment: @AggieKidd Thanks! I thought of that idea re "are", but forgot to put it in. I'll edit.

Comment: I don't think I would have ever figured it out. Well done.

Comment: Re: pies -- scarf can also be used as a verb as in "to scarf [something] down", like to eat quickly.  If you are a fan of pie, you may scarf it.